# How convex is $F$? Strict, strong, or not necessarily convex at all?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-completion

Consider the following function:
$$
F(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) = \|X_1 X_3^{\top} - Y_1\|_F^2 + \|X_2 X_3^{\top} - Y_2\|_F^2 + \|X_2 X_4^{\top} - Y_3\|_F^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^4 \|X_i\|_F^2,
$$
where $X_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times r}$, $X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2 \times r}$, $X_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_3 \times r}$ , and $X_4 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_4 \times r}$.  The dimensions $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4$ are different.

I know that when considering each of the matrices separately (fixing all others), $F$ is strongly convex in each of these block coordinates.  But I am not sure whether it is convex (at all) in all of its coordinates simultaneously.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm and $Y_1,Y_2$, and $Y_3$ are given matrices of appropriate dimension.

Comment: What does $\|\cdot\|_F$ mean here?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.  Sorry.  I'll edit my question.

Comment: As a warm-up, is $(xy-1)^2$ convex on $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: It is not.  Great warm-up example. Thanks!